# how can i make the text continue animate when im not place the cursor on the text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

im trying to make the text animate on the page but when i place the cursor on the text is stop animate and when i move the cursor theres no move on the text ?
im understand the hover function but how can i make the text continue animate when im not place the cursor on the text ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start").click(function() {
        $("#par").animate({
            fontSize: "40px",
            left : "952px",
        },3000)});
    $("#par").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop()
    });
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <button type="button" id="start">click here</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop">STOP</button>

    <p id="par" style="font-size: 0px;position: absolute;right: 0px;">hello world</p>

    <!-- <img src="img/704936.png" width="300" alt=""> -->


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery has an event called "[.mouseleave()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)".

You can attach a function to this event of #par, that does the same animation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#start").click(function() {
            $("#par").animate({
                fontSize: "40px",
                left : "952px",
            },3000)});
        $("#par").hover(function(){
            $(this).stop()
        });
        $("#par").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                fontSize: "40px",
                left : "952px",
            },3000)
        });
    });
```